# Cannot read property 'client' of undefined in create method for google sheet

Tags: angular, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have tried to get google spreadsheetId using google sheet create method i have install gapi also configured my ts.config.json file also i install gapi locally.

```
   {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["gapi"]
    }
   }

And my create method 

   var gapi : any;
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({
    properties: {
      title: title
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log('Spreadsheet ID: ' + response.result.spreadsheetId);
  });
   I got following error "Cannot read property 'client' of undefined", I need help On this issue. Here i am trying to save excel data values into google sheet that purpose i need google spreedsheetId.
```

Comment: you need to initialize the gapi variable. What tutorial do you follow?

Comment: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/browser-samples/blob/master/sheets/snippets/snippets.js. i am following this example

Comment: ok, edited my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiliaze the value of `gapi`. Here:

```
var gapi : any;
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create...
```

You create a variable without a value (=> `undefined`) and then you try to access it `gapi.client`... That does not make any sense.

You have first to have `gapi = ...`, through your code or most likely a `js` file you import from google API.

Follow closely [that tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the) for example, to get up and running.

**Edit:**

I don't know your framework, but it looks like you just need to add this to your html:

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Comment: I am using angular 6 for UI